# Named Query with like in where clause

Tags: java, sql, jpa, named-query

Is it possible to have a like in a where clause in a named query? I am trying to do the following but am getting exceptions

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Place.getPlaceForCityAndCountryName",
query = "SELECT p FROM Place p WHERE " +
        "lower(p.city) like :city and " +
        "lower(p.countryName) like :countryName");
```

I tried adding % as you would do in normal SQL but get exceptions compiling.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you take the second like out of the lower() function :)

Comment: As @Davos555 points, there is a parenthesis and a quote missing: `"lower(p.countryName) like :countryName");`

Comment: yes thanks - I copied this from a more complicated example and did not change it correctly. I'll update the question now

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can't have the % in the `NamedQuery`, but you can have it in the value you assign the parameter.

As in:

```
String city = "needle";
query.setParamter("city", "%" + city + "%");
```

Comment: How to do this when you have multiple city values.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use CONCAT function

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Place.getPlaceForCityAndCountryName",
     query = "SELECT p FROM Place p WHERE " +
        "lower(p.city) like CONCAT(:city,'%')");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
@Query("select c from Curso c where c.descripcion like CONCAT(:descripcion,'%')")

List<Curso> findByDescripcionIgnoreCase(@Param("descripcion") String descripcion);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

With JPA only, without Spring Data Jpa, you must define named query without `%` and then include the pattern itself with `%` as a part of the value, as described by @esej:

```
  @NamedQuery(
    name = ParametersQueryOnEntityEntity.Queries.BY_LIKE,
    query = "SELECT e FROM SomeEntity e WHERE name LIKE :name")
```

With Spring's `@Query` you can define the query itself with `%` included and pass only a pattern value in the method:

```
  @Query("SELECT e FROM SomeEntity e WHERE name LIKE %:name%")
  List<SomeEntity> byLike(@Param(PARAM_NAME) String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using positional parameters, you can use this way

```
@Query("select p from ABC p where p.name like CONCAT('%',?1,'%') ")
```