# Named JPA Query with 2 arguments

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am creating a named JPA query . It needs to fetch all records that meet a manager name and status . This is how i have created .

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Claims.viewMgrClaims", query = "SELECT c FROM Claims c WHERE c.mgrname = :mgrname AND " 
+ "c.status like :stat")
```

i created it following the example given here [Named Query with like in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912320/named-query-with-like-in-where-clause)

I am however unsure how my call should look like . For example i am unsure how to use setParameter with two fields . I used this for a different query and it works fine .

```
List<Claims> l = em.createNamedQuery("Claims.findByMgrname").setParameter("mgrname", MgrName).getResultList();
```

But what should i use for my new NamedQuery ? I cant get it right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call like this:

```
 List<Claims> l = (List<Claims>)em.createNamedQuery("Claims.findByMgrname")
   .setParameter("mgrname", MgrName)
   .setParameter("stat", statVar)
   .getResultList();
```

Comment: Yes i got it after going through the above links . Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I got it after a little more Googling

For people who come here looking here is a good link [Named JPA Query With Two Parameters](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/NamedQueryWithTwoParameters.htm)