# Java Named Query

Tags: java, jpql, named

I'm trying to create a Java named query which does the following postgres query:

```
select * from call_attempt where result is NULL and id like '0000000101%';
```

The 0000000101 is set to id in my code, so this is what I want to do, but it's malformed:  (I'm not sure how to set the id field while using the % and it has to be inside ' ')

```
@NamedQuery(name = AttemptEntity.JQL.NOTENDED,
                       query = "SELECT ae FROM AttemptEntity ae WHERE ae.result IS NULL,"
                             + " ae.correlationId LIKE '=:id%'")
```

Comment: There's a comma in the WHERE clause and also missing an `AND`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you forgot the `and`, and replaced it by a comma.

Second, the `%` must be passed as part of the argument:

```
SELECT ae FROM AttemptEntity ae WHERE ae.result IS NULL
and ae.correlationId LIKE :id
```

And then, when executing the query:

```
String id = "0000000101%";
query.setParameter("id", id);
```

Comment: this is still saying malformed ending  @NamedQuery(name = AttemptEntity.JQL.NOTENDED,
                           query = "SELECT ae FROM AttemptEntity ae WHERE ae.result IS NULL,"
                              + " AND ae.correlationId LIKE :id")

Comment: Again, remove that comma after IS NULL.

Comment: I removed that comma after NULL, and it seems ok now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the % in the NamedQuery, but you can have it in the value you assign the parameter.

```
query.setParamter("id", 0000000101+ "%");
```

You also need to add AND and remove the comma after NULL.

Reference: [Named Query with like in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912320/named-query-with-like-in-where-clause)